# Symfony using assetic and cssrewrite for resources in app directory

Tags: css, symfony, assetic

I use symfony assetic to load resources like that:

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
    '../app/Resources/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    '../app/Resources/css/jquery-ui.css'
    '../app/Resources/css/pagination.css'
    '../app/Resources/css/dropzone.css'
    '../app/Resources/css/angular-bootstrap-lightbox.css'
%}
```

All of these resources are located in symfony's `app/Resources` directory. Unfortunately this doesn't work if an image URL is used in a CSS file. I know that if my resources where in a bundle I would need to use paths like  `bundles/app/css/style.css` and CSS rewrite would work. But how do I get it working when resources are in main `app` directory?